# Sending poisonpill to Server from Client in Akka

Tags: java, akka

I have a client server program written using Java API. There am trying to send a message to server then server will send some reply message to Client.Then Client sending a poisonPill to Server. If server receives poisonpill message it has to shutdown.Below the code snippents for the same.
In ClientActor:

```
remoteActor.tell(poisonPill());
```

In ServerActor:

```
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {        
  if (message instanceof String) {          
    getSender().tell(message + " got something");       
  } else if (message instanceof PoisonPill) {           
    getContext().system().shutdown();       
  } 
}
```

But the `message instanceof PoisonPill` line is not executing, so that the server is always running.

Can anyone help me on this? why the line is not executing at all?

Comment: The only way that line does not execute is if message is always a String. Try debugging or logging.

Comment: if the message is always string , then is there anyway to check the poisonpill from client?

Comment: You remoteActor is invoking a poisonPill() method. Does it return a PoisonPill object?

Answer (score 3):

PoisonPill is automatically handled by Akka. You shouldn't terminate the ActorSystem from within the Actor. It'd be equivalent of calling System.exit(0) inside a Business Object.
If you want to stop the ServerActor, do: context.stop(self)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
remoteActor.tell(new PoisonPill());
```

Comment: remoteActor.tell(new PoisonPill());  is not working..giving compilation error

Comment: No, it's PoisonPill.getInstance()